# org-mode Modeline total for 'today' 'incorrect'?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I have set the org-clock-mode-line-total to be 'today as shown in the line from my custom.el

```
'(org-clock-mode-line-total (quote today))
```

When I have a task where I had some spent some time yesterday (Monday) and I start clocking it today(Tuesday), the amount of time that I spent from yesterday seems to be included in the mode line total.

e.g. current time is 7:45 am on Tuesday for the task shown below and my modeline total is shown to be 0:55.

```
**** STARTED Port over additions/changes to the real project.
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2018-01-30 Tue 07:35]
CLOCK: [2018-01-30 Tue 07:20]--[2018-01-30 Tue 07:30] =>  0:10
CLOCK: [2018-01-30 Tue 07:20]--[2018-01-30 Tue 07:25] =>  0:05
CLOCK: [2018-01-29 Mon 16:25]--[2018-01-29 Mon 16:55] =>  0:30
:END:
```

If I manually change Monday's log book entry to make it Sunday, the time shown on the modeline becomes correct(i.e. 0:20) . Maybe I have a wrong option setting somewhere? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Update: This seems to have been a bug which was fixed in a newer git commit.
https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/0790855c93533ce988f5b28839fdf0eca7521ad3

After some investigation, it appears that this may have to do with org-mode using UTC midnight to midnight to be  "today" as opposed to midnight as defined by my local time zone (PST). This problem goes away after setting 'org-extend-today-until' to 8 which is the difference between UTC and my time zone.

Not clear if it is a bug or incorrect setup with org-mode, emacs or something else. I started emacs with -q to not load my init file. org-mode was from the git head for today (Feb 1, 2018) and unaltered.